# Inserting multiple rows to a table which references itself

Tags: t-sql

e.g.

```
create table dbo.fktest (
id int not null primary key, 
val varchar(100) not null, 
idparent int null)    

alter table dbo.fktest add constraint FK_fktest foreign key (idparent) references fktest(id)    
go
-- one row references another row, which isn't in the table at the start of the insert command.
insert dbo.fktest values (2, 'two', 1), (1, 'one', null)
```

Will the insert statement at the end always succeed? It seems to, but not sure if it is by luck or guaranteed.

Comment: Good question +1.  It seems that SQL Server is treating the entire insert as a single statement, and only checks the constraints once afterwards.  But I could find no documentation for this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it *is* a single statement... You can check it simply be adding a trigger for insert to the table and see it only fires once for an insert statement like this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - if you post your comment as an answer, i'll mark it as the answer - as that seems to be the closest. I think it makes sense that constraints are checked at the end, otherwise it would be impossible to do something like: insert dbo.fktest values (3, 'three', 3)   - which works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empirically, it appears to be the case that the following `INSERT` statement is in fact a single statement:

```
insert dbo.fktest values (2, 'two', 1), (1, 'one', null)
```

Evidence for this is that should the insert fail, the entire statement would be rolled back.  Also, as @Zohar commented above, we could put a trigger on the above insert, and it would only fire once.

As a result of this, the insert only needs to pass constraint checks once all records have been inserted.  This implies that the order does not matter, at least with regard to constraints.  That is, the two following insert statements are both valid:

```
insert dbo.fktest values (2, 'two', 1), (1, 'one', null);
insert dbo.fktest values (1, 'one', null), (2, 'two', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be better off inserting all nulls for the fkey and then updating the fkey to what you want it to refer to.

The insert into statement runs as a single transaction, so it should work. Its not luck!!